# Задача "Постройте квадрат" | C++

Tags: математика, геометрия

Условие задачи выглядит так:

**Заданы координаты точек A(xa, ya) и B(xb, yb). Найдите две точки C и D такие, что ACBD — квадрат, причём AB — его диагональ.**

**Формат ввода**

**В единственной строке находятся четыре целых числа xa, ya, xb, yb, по модулю не превышающих 1000. Гарантируется, что точки A и B не совпадают.**

**Формат вывода**

**В первой строке выведите координаты точки C, во второй — координаты точки D. Точки можно выводить в произвольном порядке. Координаты необходимо вывести с точностью до пятого знака после запятой.**

Помогите, пожалуйста, а то идей совсем нет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ладно, раз я сначала не разобрался в задаче и мог навести трехминутным :) комментарием не туда, вот решение:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Попробуйте сами составить уравнения для точек C, D и решить их. Простейший вариант — расстояния от С (и D) до A и B равны и составляют... во сколько раз длина стороны меньше диагонали?

Comment: А зачем Вы пишете про расстояния, если уже показали хорошее решение без их вычисления? Для плюрализма :) ?

Comment: @MBo Я рассказал вариант, КАК получить ответ. Вдруг человек захочет что-то сделать САМ?